# app.module.ts 404 (Not Found) in Angular 2 with systemjs

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, systemjs

Here are my imports to **index.html**:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

I'm getting error: app/app.module.ts 404 (Not Found)

This is my folder stracture:

```
- app
   - app.module.ts
   - app.compontent.ts
- main.ts
```

The strange thing is when everyting is under the same folder (like this):

```
- angular2
  - app
    - app.module.ts
    - app.compontent.ts
  - main.ts
```

now everything working. Why is that?

**main.ts** file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**tsconfig**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,

    "inlineSources": true,

    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the './' is starting at the root directory of the project. Maybe when you remove the angular2 folder, the root is changed and therefore the main.ts import cannot find the app directory

Answer (score 0):

To import .ts files you need to configure the default extension in package configuration.

```
SystemJS.config({
  packages: {
    "app": {
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  }
});
```

However, in your example you seem to be importing `main.js` which is at odds with the directory structure you indicated when you wrote

> - app
>
>   - app.module.ts
>   - app.compontent.ts
> - main.ts